# Inflation of Custom Preference failed

Tags: java, android

I wanted to make my own custom preference. But when I start the activity with the PreferenceFragment that contains the custom preference it fails with the following error:

> 01-13 07:11:26.117 14403-14403/com.laudien.p1xelfehler.batterywarner_pro E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                              Process: com.laudien.p1xelfehler.batterywarner_pro, PID: 14403
>                                                                                              java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.laudien.p1xelfehler.batterywarner_pro/com.laudien.p1xelfehler.batterywarner.Activities.SettingsActivity.SettingsActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #42: Error inflating class com.laudien.p1xelfehler.batterywarner.Activities.SettingsActivity.SliderPreference
>                                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
>                                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
>                                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
>                                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
>                                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
>                                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
>                                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
>                                                                                               Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #42: Error inflating class com.laudien.p1xelfehler.batterywarner.Activities.SettingsActivity.SliderPreference
>                                                                                                  at android.preference.GenericInflater.createItem(GenericInflater.java:388)
>                                                                                                  at android.preference.GenericInflater.createItemFromTag(GenericInflater.java:432)
>                                                                                                  at android.preference.GenericInflater.rInflate(GenericInflater.java:483)
>                                                                                                  at android.preference.GenericInflater.rInflate(GenericInflater.java:495)
>                                                                                                  at android.preference.GenericInflater.inflate(GenericInflater.java:327)
>                                                                                                  at android.preference.GenericInflater.inflate(GenericInflater.java:264)
>                                                                                                  at android.preference.PreferenceManager.inflateFromResource(PreferenceManager.java:280)
>                                                                                                  at android.preference.PreferenceFragment.addPreferencesFromResource(PreferenceFragment.java:326)
>                                                                                                  at com.laudien.p1xelfehler.batterywarner.Activities.SettingsActivity.NewSettingsFragment.onCreate(NewSettingsFragment.java:14)
>                                                                                                  at android.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:2335)
>                                                                                                  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:949)
>                                                                                                  at android.app.BackStackRecord.setLastIn(BackStackRecord.java:857)
>                                                                                                  at android.app.BackStackRecord.calculateFragments(BackStackRecord.java:897)
>                                                                                                  at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:727)
>                                                                                                  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1578)
>                                                                                                  at android.app.FragmentController.execPendingActions(FragmentController.java:371)
>                                                                                                  at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6680)
>                                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2609)
>                                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707) 
>                                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
>                                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460) 
>                                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
>                                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
>                                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865) 
>                                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755) 
>                                                                                               Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException:  [class android.content.Context, interface android.util.AttributeSet]
>                                                                                                  at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2204)
>                                                                                                  at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1683)
>                                                                                                  at android.preference.GenericInflater.createItem(GenericInflater.java:378)
>                                                                                                  at android.preference.GenericInflater.createItemFromTag(GenericInflater.java:432) 
>                                                                                                  at android.preference.GenericInflater.rInflate(GenericInflater.java:483) 
>                                                                                                  at android.preference.GenericInflater.rInflate(GenericInflater.java:495) 
>                                                                                                  at android.preference.GenericInflater.inflate(GenericInflater.java:327) 
>                                                                                                  at android.preference.GenericInflater.inflate(GenericInflater.java:264) 
>                                                                                                  at android.preference.PreferenceManager.inflateFromResource(PreferenceManager.java:280) 
>                                                                                                  at android.preference.PreferenceFragment.addPreferencesFromResource(PreferenceFragment.java:326) 
>                                                                                                  at com.laudien.p1xelfehler.batterywarner.Activities.SettingsActivity.NewSettingsFragment.onCreate(NewSettingsFragment.java:14) 
>                                                                                                  at android.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:2335) 
>                                                                                                  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:949) 
>                                                                                                  at android.app.BackStackRecord.setLastIn(BackStackRecord.java:857) 
>                                                                                                  at android.app.BackStackRecord.calculateFragments(BackStackRecord.java:897) 
>                                                                                                  at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:727) 
>                                                                                                  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1578) 
>                                                                                                  at android.app.FragmentController.execPendingActions(FragmentController.java:371) 
>                                                                                                  at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6680) 
>                                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2609) 
>                                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707) 
>                                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
>                                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460) 
>                                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
>                                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
>                                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865) 
>                                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)

This is my SliderPreference.java:

```
public class SliderPreference extends Preference {
@Override
protected View onCreateView(ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.preference_slider, parent, false);
}

public SliderPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
}

@Override
protected void onClick() {
    super.onClick();
}
```

}

This is the preference_slider.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView_lowBattery"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Title"
    android:textSize="18sp" />

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkBox_lowBattery"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/enabled" />

<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/seekBar_lowBattery"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

This is the NewSettingsFragment.java:

```
public class NewSettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(getActivity(), R.xml.preferences, false);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
}
```

}

I added the preference in the preference.xml file just like that:

```
<com.laudien.p1xelfehler.batterywarner.Activities.SettingsActivity.SliderPreference />
```

Thank you for your help! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All right guys, i found the solution for myself.

You just have to use ALL constructors in the custom preference class. Like this:

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
public SliderPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
}

public SliderPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
}

public SliderPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public SliderPreference(Context context) {
    super(context);
}
```